# Wordpress gravity forms - show popup depending on select value

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a page where user can select different options. Depending on this options (A, B, A & B) I want to show a popup if A or B is chosen when submitting, offering A & B (upselling) with 2 options: Continue and Upgrade.

There is a price in the bottom and based on selection will add to the price.

[image]

It's pretty simple task for those who familiar with javascript and jQuery, but I cant figure out how to do it with wordpress gforms.
Will update post if figure out futher.

Answer (score 1):

If your form ajax submission is not enable than you can do it with simple jquery like

```
$('#gform_1 input[type=submit]').on('click',function(){

});
```

you can also put this code under gform_post_render event

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/